# How do I compare the 4th column of two different CSV files to check if they are the same?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine if two columns (both the 4th column in) are the same, row by row, and if they are to spit out in a check column that they match. I  keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute '_4'

The purpose was to compare two methods of removing whitespace from the column "Description". I wanted to make sure that the method I used removes the same whitespace from the previous method.

This the section of the code that I am having issues with:

trans is CSV 1
Check1 is CSV 2

```
trans.to_csv('combined5.csv')

trans['check'] = None

check1 = pd.read_csv('combined2.csv')

check1.head()

    Account Number  Currency    Date        Description 
0   10200313950       CAD      2018-10-01   TFR 8060 0309039

for t in trans.itertuples():
    for c in check1.itertuples():
        if t._1 == c._1:
            trans.at[t.Index, 'check'] = 'match'
        else:
            trans.at[t.Index, 'check'] = 'not match'
```

I was trying to get it to tell me on the CSV if it does or doesnt match.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It would help us if you would show us your data and the desired output. As I understand, now you are trying to check if two `columns` in two different `.csv` files are absolutely identical, meaning each value in each row is the same?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding!

Yes, I am updating an old file for work. Previously they had been using RE to remove whitespace for a certain column, instead of using .strip. So I changed it and wanted to make sure that the same whitespace has been removed from the columns. So, I wanted to confirm that they are the same using, if that makes sense?

so Check1.CSV is the original version and trans is the new CSV that the program is creating. 

I'll add some more details into my post. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv('file_1.csv')
df2 = pandas.read_csv('file_2.csv')

if df1.loc[:, 3] == df2.loc[:, 3]:
    print("Both are Equal")
else:
    print("Both are not Equal")
```